# How to convert 64bit void pointer into 32bit void pointer?

Tags: c++, ios, c, audio

I have a buffer(contains audio data) which is void pointer. In 32bit system, it's size is 4 byte and in 64 bit system, it's size is 8 byte. So how can i convert 64bit void pointer into 32bit void pointer without loosing any data ?

Comment: A pointer on one system is unlikely to be valid on another system, so conversion of the pointer will not help you. If you want to transfer data between the systems, then transfer the data, and allocate a new block of memory (with its own address) for it on the destination system.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? And how do you exactly use this "pointer".

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Why not make this comment an answer?

Comment: @alk : I wasn't sure I understood the intent of the OP, and was waiting for some further clarification. That never arrived ...

Answer (score 1):

As long as the value in your 64-bit pointer **plus** the size of your buffer is less than `2^32` you can just use the lower 32 bit of your pointer. For example `uint32_ptr ptr32 = static_cast<uint32_ptr>(ptr64)`. It is, however, not a best practice to mess with pointers like this.

In addition, I assume you'll be using these pointers in the same process on the same machine. Any other application will fail!

Comment: well, you have to define it yourself. You can't use `void*` because obviously it's 64-bit. So you have to define a 32-bit unsigned integer type to hold its value. for example `using uint32_ptr = uint32_t` will do the job. It's just a cosmetic clarification to mark the integer as a 32-bit pointer.

Comment: I'd consider this an offset, not a pointer anymore. A pointer absolutly addresses memory. This is **not** possible with a 32-bit wide integer in a 64bit environment.

Comment: That's true. But that's about the only way to do this as far as I know, so correct me if I'm wrong.